# Highlight the title of a section and one bibliography output of bibtex

Tags: biblatex, highlighting, section-titles

I am trying to highlight one specific title of my section by using the `\hlc` command, but it does not seem to work at all. When I try this: `\hlc[green]{\section{Title section5}}`, the title of the section disappears completely. Whereas, when I try this command `\section{\hlc[green]{Title section 5}}` I get [image: This]... Any suggestions on how to fix this please?

Also, I do not know how to go about highlighting one bibliography line of my bibtex file.

Comment: The details of your question are not fully clear at the moment. I tried `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\section{\hlc[green]{Title section 5}}
\end{document}` and that works without problems. Could you make a similar small but complete document for your situation that doet not work, and add that to your question?

Comment: There appear to be two questions in one here. Neither of which is particularly easy to answer without a lot more information about your document (ideally in the form of a short example document that reproduces the relevant bit of the status quo with as little code as possible, a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Please split the two questions (one about highlighting section headings and one about highlighting bibliography entries) into two and add a suitable example document to each question.